# ERROR The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am building an app with React Native and Expo and i am trying to implement authentication in the app but i am getting this error and i can't find a solution.

Basically i have 2 navigation stacks `AppStack` & `AuthStack` in my `App.js`. `AppStack` will be shown if the user is authenticated and if the user is not authenticated then `AuthStack` will be shown to the user.

So i am conditionally rendering the stacks with ternary operator as you can see in the **App.js** code below. The stacks are working fine i mean if user is authenticated then `AppStack` is shown and if not then `AuthStack` is shown.

Now the Signin screen is present in `AuthStack` and when a user logs in successfully he should be navigated to Home screen `navigation.navigate("Home")` which is present in `AppStack`. But when a user logs in it throws me this error.

```
ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator.                                                                                    
Do you have a screen named 'Home'?                                                      
If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production
```

**Here is the App.js code:**

```
const AppStack = () => {
    return (
      <>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#000"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Forgot Password" component={ForgotPwd} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#2a454e"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Check Your Inbox" component={ForgotPwdNext} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#00dfc0"}, headerTintColor: "#3a5864"}} /> 
        <Stack.Screen name="Change Password" component={ChangePwd} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#e5322b"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </>  
      )
  }
  
  const AuthStack = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#1b4152"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} /> 
          <Stack.Screen name="Signin" component={Signin} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#5549ab"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#26dec0"}, headerTintColor: "#35474f"}} /> 
          <Stack.Screen name="Verify Phone Number" component={VerifyPhone} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#d268cc"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Logged Out" component={LoggedOut} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#5a6e7f"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
       </Stack.Navigator> 
      </>
      )
  }
  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer style={styles.root}>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      {isAuthenticated ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  ) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This exact problem is addressed [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow#dont-manually-navigate-when-conditionally-rendering-screens).

Your `AuthStack` doesn't know anything about `AppStack` and vice versa. Hence `navigation.navigate("Home")` from `AuthStack` will fail.

When `isAuthenticated` is changed React Navigation will automatically navigate to correct screen. This is possible when `isAuthenticated` state is managed globally using React Context (or by using any state management library like Redux, Zustand etc).

Check this official [example](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/example/src/Screens/AuthFlow.tsx) which more or less resembles your authentication flow.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot navigate from `Signin` to `Home`. You can only navigate between screens that share a parent navigator  or grandfather if you have nested navigators. Here is a quote from the [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/) talking about this specific navigator they created:

> Said another way, we can only navigate to routes that have been defined on our navigator — we cannot navigate to an arbitrary component

The common way  is to have a way to change `isAuthenticated` to true in `Signin` instead of navigating, and the below condition in `App.js` will do the job. For that you can pass a state setter from `App` to `Signin` using a [`context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for example.

```
{isAuthenticated ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
```

Answer (score 0):

somehow managed to solve the error by registering AppStack as a screen in AuthStack and also registering AuthStack as screen in AppStack like this:

```
const AppStack = () => {
    return (
      <>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#000"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Forgot Password" component={ForgotPwd} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#2a454e"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Check Your Inbox" component={ForgotPwdNext} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#00dfc0"}, headerTintColor: "#3a5864"}} /> 
        <Stack.Screen name="Change Password" component={ChangePwd} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#e5322b"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="AuthStack" component={AuthStack} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </>  
      )
  }
```

---

NOTE THE LAST SCREEN IN AppStack ABOVE

---

And same with the AppStack

```
const AuthStack = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#1b4152"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} /> 
          <Stack.Screen name="Signin" component={Signin} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#5549ab"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#26dec0"}, headerTintColor: "#35474f"}} /> 
          <Stack.Screen name="Verify Phone Number" component={VerifyPhone} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#d268cc"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Logged Out" component={LoggedOut} options={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#5a6e7f"}, headerTintColor: "white"}} />
          <Stack.Screen name="AppStack" component={AppStack} />
       </Stack.Navigator> 
      </>
      )
  }
```

But now the problem is i am getting 2 navigation headers When i switch between screens which are in different stacks i mean if i go from one screen to another which are both in same stack then 2 headers doesn't appear, 2 headers only appear when i go from a screen which is in suppose Stack-A to Stack-B

Comment: You can hide the header. e.g. options={{headerShown: false}}